# What does it mean if no lag lies outside the 95% confidence interval in the PACF plot?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, autocorrelation, acf-pacf

I have time series data and started to test for autocorrelation with the help of the ACF and PACF plot after differencing my dependent variable (diff_gap). I type in the following code:

`acf(final_dataset_diff$diff_gap)`
`pacf(final_dataset_diff$diff_gap)`

then I got the following plots:

[image: ACF Plot]

[image: PACF Plot]

So, my question is, how I should interpret the PACF Plot where no lag is outside the blue line? How can I now say which number of lagged variables could be appropriate for my ARIMA model (I want to refine it with the AIC later)?

Thanks for your comments!

Comment: The charts suggest that there is no significant autocorrelation in your data. If you have already differenced your series then perhaps ARIMA(0,1,0) is a good fit for your original variable based on the above charts.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I then continued with computing several ARIMAs and the ARIMA(0,1,1) was the one with the lowest AIC. I then continue with adding one by one my independent variables and with some variables the AIC becomes smaller and with other independent variables, the AIC becomes bigger. Does it mean that only those IVs have an influence on my DV where the AIC becomes smaller or what does the ARIMA tells me? And how can I now develop my model, meaning which method can I now use to determine the coefficients?